# Cpp pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

could you please help me understand this.

I have function that needs "**char ***argv**";

As far as I understand it's :
   *pointer to pointer to array of char pointers*.

something like this: "**char *arr[]**" ?

```
char xx1 = '1';
char xx2 = '2';
char *argv[] = {&xx1,&xx2};
```

Then I call my function with **gtk_init (&argc, &argv);**

And get error:

```
main.cpp:43:31: error: cannot convert ‘char* (*)[2]’ to ‘char***’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void gtk_init(int*, char***)’
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Close.  `char *arr[]` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer to an array.

Comment: replace each `*` by `pointer to`. then append the left most type.

Comment: ***argv is pointer to a pointer to a pointer, which depending on what's in those pointers can be a synonym for a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: `argv` is already a `char**` because it's an array of strings.  You're passing a pointer to gtk_init, which is why it needs to be a `char***`.  In this case it's a pointer to an array of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `char***` is a "pointer to pointer to pointer to char". No arrays involved at all. Your `argv` is an "array of 2 pointer to char". The name of your array, `argv`, will decay to a pointer to its first element in certain circumstances - this pointer will have type `char**`, or "pointer to pointer to char".

When you do `&argv`, you get a `char* (*)[2]`, or a "pointer to array of 2 pointer to char". Which is not what you want. That's because you're taking the address of an array, not of a pointer.

Also, you're going to have a problem with the fact that you're pointers in `argv` are just pointing at single `char`s, not at null-terminated strings. `gtk_init` will almost certainly be expecting null-terminated strings.

So what you can you do? Try this:

```
char xx1[] = "1"; // Now these are null-terminated strings
char xx2[] = "2";
char* argv[] = {xx1, xx2};
char** argvp = argv; // Use the fact that the array will decay
gtk_init(&argc, &argv); // &argv will now be a char***
```

The reason for using arrays for the strings is because we need the `char`s to be non-const, but a `char* str = "hello";` style declaration is deprecated - it must be `const char*`. However, by using arrays, the contents of the string literal are copied into our array, so we can freely make it non-`const`.

`gtk_init` really just expects you to pass the `argc` and `argv` parameters of your main function to it like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  // ...
}
```

You may now ask "But why is `&argv` now allowed? `argv` is the same type as in the question! Why don't we get a pointer to array again?" Actually, `argv` is not the same type, despite how much it looks like it is. When you define a function that takes an array argument, it actually gets transformed to a pointer. So the definition of `main` is equivalent to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);
```

So when we do `&argv`, we're totally fine, because it gives us a `char***`.

As @OmnipotentEntity says in the comments - you'd better have a good excuse for not passing the parameters of `main` to `gtk_init`.

Comment: It should also be noted, that `gtk_init` is intended to take your main's `argc` and `argv`, so unless you're doing something special or weird, you should probably just pass those.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Your comment is a worthy note. :) Edit: Actually, I will edit it in.

Comment: Yes I'm doing weird stuff. Trying to use GTK from Haxe so I'm binding some haxe functions to cpp.
Thank you very much, this worked.